# I can´t use negative arguments in openvz

Tags: server, openvz

I have this problem with openVZ
how I can fix it?

```
root@pc03:/file/launch# cp -R plugins/!(*og*) /backup
-bash: !: event not found
```

Answer (score 2):

First run

```
shopt -s extglob
```

and now

```
cp -R plugins/!(*og*) /backup
```

works.

Disable the behavior with

```
shopt -u extglob
```

---

From `man bash`

```
If  the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the following
description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
by a |. Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the
following sub-patterns:

     ?(pattern-list)
            Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
     *(pattern-list)
            Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
     +(pattern-list)
            Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
     @(pattern-list)
            Matches one of the given patterns
     !(pattern-list)
            Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 16 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this answer, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! ;-)